# show that $(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots (1+x^{2^n}) = \frac{1-x^{2^{(n+1)}}}{1-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve the following question in my textbook, one way to go at this would probably be to use induction to prove the statement. But I am looking for alternativ ways to prove this.

$$(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots(1+x^{2^n}) = \frac{1-x^{2^{(n+1)}}}{1-x^2}$$

**My attempt at a solution:**

The RHS in the statement looks like the formula for a geometric series. The LHS does not however and I am stuck...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $(1+x^2)(1-x^2) = (1-x^4)$. Repeat $n$ times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very much appreciated. Still not sure if I understand what you are going for here. If you have the time I would love a bit more explanation of your thoughts.

Comment: @LukasArvidsson: I guess one can argue that any proof of that fact would use induction in disguise, so I thought of the easiest argument that just tells *"you can see this pattern, no need for induction"*. When you multiply the LHS by the denominator of the RHS, you just see all the terms "disappearing" turning the $+$ in the consecutive term to $-$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This was actually exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Ilya:

$$(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdot...\cdot(1+x^{2^n})=\frac{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdot...\cdot(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x^2}$$
Using repeatedly the identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$
$$\frac{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\cdot...\cdot(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x^2}=\frac{(1-x^4)(1+x^4)\cdot...\cdot(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x^2}$$
$$.....$$
$$\frac{(1-x^{2^n})\cdot(1+x^{2^n})}{1-x^2}=\frac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^2}$$

Comment: I was writing my answer, which is similar to yours, a yours appeared!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: I actually elaborated on Ilya's comment.

Comment: Thank you for you clarification of Ilyas answer Arain. Much appreciated!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to multiply both sides by $1 - x^{2}$. The left side will then simplify quickly and easily.

Comment: Hi Geoff! As far as I can understand this is the same approach that Ilya was taking.

Comment: Well, the idea is the same, but I was trying to be a bit more explicit. The left side "collapses" a lot when multiplied by $1-x^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n = 1, 2 $  the statement is true (can be checked by hand). Assume that the statement is true for $n = k.$ Now
$$
(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots(1+x^{2^k})(1 + x^{2^{k + 1}}) = \frac{1-x^{2^{(k+1)}}}{1-x^2}(1 + x^{2^{k + 1}}) = \frac{1-x^{2^{(k+ 1 +1)}}}{1-x^2}.
$$
So the statement is true for $n = k + 1.$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Factor the numerator as a successive differences of squares.