# Prove that ($2^{(2^0)}$ + 1) * ($2^{(2^1)}$ + 1)* ... *($2^{(2^k)}$ + 1) = $2^{(2^{(k+1))}} - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, exponentiation

($2^{(2^0)}$ + 1) * ($2^{(2^1)}$ + 1)* ... *($2^{(2^k)}$ + 1) = $2^{(2^{(k+1)})} - 1$

I've seen this is true for k = 1,2,3,4

All help appreciated. I've never worked with an exponent to an exponent before, so I don't know how to apply rules of a finite geometric series.

Comment: Do you know induction?

Comment: No, I have no experience with induction, but if you have a proof with induction, I can still try to understand it

Comment: Or just look at this in binary, and see that it is "obvious" (that's not enough of a proof, and it requires some familiarity with binary, but if so it really is pretty obvious that the pattern continues indefinitely).

Comment: Do you really need mostleft bracket in title?

Comment: @RobertZ did you mean k?

Comment: Let $=2$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042128/show-that-1x21x41x8-cdots-1x2n-frac1-x2n11-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily shown with induction :

let
$$F(n) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 2^{(2^k)} + 1 \right).$$
If $n = 1$, it is trivial that $F(1) = 2^{(2^0)} + 1 = 2^{(2^1)} - 1 = 3.$

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, suppose that
$$F(n) = 2^{(2^n)} - 1,$$
and multiply $2^{(2^{n})} + 1$ on both sides :
$$(2^{(2^{n})} + 1) F(n) = F(n+1) = (2^{(2^{n})} + 1)(2^{(2^n)} - 1) = 2^{(2^{n+1}\:)} - 1$$
and the statement is proved.